# Laravel try to save a class object into session

Tags: php, laravel, object, session, serialization

I am trying to save a class object into session but somehow it is throwing the "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" error.

What can I do to fix it?

Below is my code

```
public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
        $listing=Listing::find($id);

        
        $cart = new Cart(null); 
        $cart->add($listing,$listing->id); //this is working 
        Session::put('cart',$cart);
        Session::save();
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
```

Below is my class

```
class Cart {
    public $items=null;
    public $totalQty=0;
    public $totalPrice=0;

    public function __construct($oldCart){
        if($oldCart){
            $this->items=$oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty=$oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice=$oldCart->totalPrice;
        }
    }
    public function add($item, $id){
        $this->items[$id]=['qty'=>0,'price'=>0,'item'=>$item];
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice+=10000;
        
    }
}
```

Here is the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrHCQ.png)

(Laravel, Session, Object, Serealize)

Here is the model

```
<?php namespace Nanolution\Listing\Models;


class Listing extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    

    public $table = 'nanolution_listing_';

    public $rules = [
    ];

    public $attachMany=[
        "gallery"=>"System\Models\File"
    ];

    public $hasMany=[
        'testimonials'=>"Nanolution\Listing\Models\Testimonial"
    ];

    public $belongsToMany=[
        'categories'=>["Nanolution\Listing\Models\Category",
                        'table'=>'nanolution_listing_list_cate'
        
        ]

    ];
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @lagbox listing is just a Eloquent model

Comment: can you show the model

Comment: Yes its edited.

Comment: would need to see the base Model and the trait but it seems like something has set a closure on that model instance of Listing ..

Comment: I set it so 'item'=>$item->title, and the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Your `Cart` contains a reference to your `Listing` model. Models cannot be serialized, because they contain references to objects that contain references to closures.

If possible, update your `Cart` to not keep the reference to the `Listing` model.

If your `Cart` requires the `Listing` reference, then you will need to update your code to handle serializing and unserializing models. Laravel has a trait for this for the queuing system you can attempt to use. I don't know if it will work, though.

To attempt this, add the `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` trait to your `Cart` class. The way the trait works is that, behind the scenes, instead of attempting to serialize the entire model, it serializes the model identifier. Then, when the object is unserialized, it retrieves a fresh instance of the model from the database.